# Instruction set used by the Broadcom BCM2835

Tags: raspberry-pi, emulation

I want to implement an emulator for the Raspberry Pi Zero for fun, but I just want to be absolutely sure before I begin, is it the ARMv6 instruction set that is used by Broadcom BCM2835?

Answer (score 0):

From http://elinux.org/RPi_Hardware

> CPU core: ARM1176JZF-S ARM11 core clocked at 700MHz; ARM VFP. The ARM11 core implements the ARMv6 Architecture. For details on ARM instruction sets and naming conventions, see ARM architecture and List of ARM microprocessor cores

The Pi3 uses a later chip but that can still do ARMv6

Comment: Awesome. I poked around on the site that you linked to and found that the ARM1176JZF-S actually uses an extended version of ARMv6 called ARMv6Z.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ARM_microarchitectures